# Start scroll bar below a particular div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I have a webpage with a navigation div (class="top-section") at the top followed by some other div (class="display"). I want that the scroll bar on the right starts below the top-section class so that the full width is taken by the div in the top-section.

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcQPS.png)

The CSS for the two divs is here

```css
.top-section{
  background-image: url('images/landscape-image.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.display{
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  padding-bottom: 5vh;
  margin-top: 7.5vh;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

The body is structured as

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="col-12 top-section">
    
    </div>

    <div className="display col-11 col-md-9 col-lg-7 mx-auto">
        
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thank You

Comment: How is your HTML structured? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added the HTML for body section in the code above.

Comment: It is not possible! what you can do is wrap all your content in a div except your navbar and then set `overflow-y: auto` to that particular div and with that make sure to remove body scrollbar like `body::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none }`.

Comment: Thank you so much. That does solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution is to have a parent and child heirarchy.

## Solution

1. Make a parent `div` having

```
 background-image: url('images/landscape-image.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 top: 0;
```

2. Make two children divs, first one with header having the

```
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 2;
 top: 0;
 height: 2vh;
```

3. The second one with class `display` having

```
 height: 98vh;
 overflow-y: scroll;
```